# Google Sheets: Calculate the number of coloured cells IF the check box is marked

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to calculate the number of coloured cells in a column where the check box is also marked.

For example, in column F, there are 2 green cells in rows with marked check boxes.  I have failed to work out a formula that would help me do this.  I am using the function by colour add-on to count number of coloured cells.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id5tk.png)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QslPF9OvcyEnTWcHXk6jaw4bM7dcLbq9-lFXZjVd75s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does the sheet changes shape or the columns will always stay the same? If it always stays the same you could implement the answer below with an onEdit trigger  so it will get updated every time there is a change on the sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- I would use a custom function to do that and then use it as a formula in the sheet.
  Please read more about [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) and their limitations.
- They are not refreshed as regular formulas but only when an argument changes. Please look online for workarounds on this issue if it is a bottleneck in your project.

### Solution:

Click on `Tools => Script editor` on the top menu of the spreadsheet file, copy & paste the below code into a blank script and click on save.

```
function countColors(checkboxesColumn,colorColumn,hexCode) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const values = sh.getRange(checkboxesColumn).getValues().flat();
  const colors = sh.getRange(colorColumn).getBackgrounds().flat();
  return values.filter((v,i)=>v==true && colors[i]==hexCode).length;
}
```

then you can use that function in your sheet as `=countColors("C3:C","F3:F","#b7e1cd")`:

[image: example]